# Deploying asp.net Mvc Web application

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, iis-7

when i was running my application from vs every thing goes OK i deployed the application and run it from IIS7 on a machine run windows 7 the website run OK but i icons and images in content folder dosn't appear in the webpages also when i try to navigate this image told me that files not found

Comment: It would help if you could provide some more information on your deployment and the project itself. Are you running from a virtual directory versus a rooted application, do you use absolute paths for your images, etc?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually the small things we overlook when programming (and deploying)

1. Make sure your virtual directory is pointed to the correct place
2. Make sure your content is all published
3. Make sure the permissions on your virtual directory is correct

More information would help to determine exactly what is going on though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are referencing your images with a path that different between VS web server and the way you have the site setup in IIS.

For example if you used

`<link href="../../Content/Somefile.css" />`

to reference a CSS file (or an image) keep in mind that path might not be correct on your IIS machine.

You might need to update such paths to something like

`<link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Somefile.css") %>  />`